# How do I generate-content of a particular type with drush 9.x+

Tags: drush

```
root@0a581055a6ad:/opt/drupal# drush genc 10 --types=article


  The "--types" option does not exist.


devel-generate:content [--kill] [--bundles [BUNDLES]] [--authors [AUTHORS]] [--feedback [FEEDBACK]] [--languages [LANGUAGES]] [--translations [TRANSLATIONS]] [--add-type-label] [--skip-fields [SKIP-FIELDS]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--notify [NOTIFY]] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--druplicon] [--] <command> [<num> [<max_comments>]]

root@0a581055a6ad:/opt/drupal# drush --version
Drush Commandline Tool 10.3.4
```

According to [the documentation](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/devel-generate/) this was an option with `drush 8.x`, but I don't see any equivalent in `drush 9.x` and up. What is the intended way to invoke `genc` for a particular node type with this new version of drush?

Comment: Going off the the error output, it would probably be `—bundles=article`

Comment: Can’t get the above to format properly, but `bundles` instead of `types`, essentially

Comment: doh! Thanks @clive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's [`--bundles`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/devel/-/blob/4.0.1/devel_generate/src/Commands/DevelGenerateCommands.php#L222) now. That's also what the error output is telling you already when echoing all possible options.

```
drush genc 10 --bundles article,page
```